# I need an contributon function for my win service instances

Tags: c#, sql, .net, function

I have an table with `Guid` as primary key. The table has contained a lot of rows already. Also, I have an `win service`, that do some set of actions with each row (possible needs read and write data from another databases). So processing of one row takes a quite lot of time. (in average about 100 seconds)

My win service works like this:

```
public class MyDto
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

while (true){
     if(time to start){
          List<MyDto> rows = LoadData();
          foreach(MyDto obj in rows){
               Process(obj);//it takes in average about 100 sec
          }
     }
}
```

I need reduce performing time of all my rows. By some reasons I decided increase insatnces of my win service. So I need that each win service will proccess own row set.

I've parametrized my `LoadData()` fun:

```
public List<MyDto> LoadData(int winServInstanceNumber){

}
```

So i need an contribution function depends from total win service instances count and concreate win service instance number.

Can you offer something better than

```
//on .net side
obj.Id.GetHashCode()%totalWinServiceInstancesCount
```

or

```
--on sql side
HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST(id as varbinary(16)))%totalWinServiceInstancesCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you need is to spin more threads to process your data. But to do this, you need a control of what you processing, in order not to process same thing twice. To get a control you can use `MSMQ`, for example, or `System.Collections.Queue`. Your service should be responsible to query database and load unprocessed rows into your queue.

Then, you can call some static method `ProcessBatch`. It will go to the queue and spin a thread(s), and pass the id(s) of the row(s) to the processor(s)/Workers. worker will only process one row. Worker can be separate EXE and run out of process. Your 'ProcessBatch' should control, what processed/not processed. It should control how many threads are currently running. You don't want to spin too many.

So

```
Service           ProcessControl          Worker
  |                       |                |
  |---Load Queue          |                |
  |         |             |                |
  |<--------|             |                |
  |                       |                |
  |-----Call When Q ----->|---Queue        |
  |                       |       |        |
  |                       |<------|        |
  |                       |                |
  |---Load Queue          |----Start------>|
  |        |              |<---Success-----|
  |<-------|              |                |
  |                       |---Permanent    |
  |-----Call When Q ----->|    Dequeue     |
  |                       |       |        |
  |                       |<------|        |
```

This is probably typical workload split that speeds up otherwise slow processes

Comment: Good point, thanks for your answer, but i was asking about contribution function. BTW vote up for your solution

Comment: @isxaker Sorry, I may miss something here. I thought, your question was about speeding up processing of your data instead of `foreach(MyDto obj in rows)`. Could you explain what does it mean to you "contribution function"? Thanks

Comment: It's a function(looks like a some hash function), depends from one(the number of current win serv instance) or two (the number of current win serv instance and the total number of win services) global settings. Also that function has one input parameter(GUID in my case). The function have to  do some "magic" with input value and return int number belongs [0; totalWinServInstancesNumber -1]; looks like a some hash from Guid in my case

Comment: So, i just want to each of my win services perorming the same amount of rows. The simplest fun is - `void fun(Guid g) { return g.GetHashCode()%totalWinServiceInstancesCount; }`

Comment: It may be still not 100% clear to me. Sounds like you looking for some load balancer. But then again, your main issue is design - if you have one service - it can control load and spin workers. And your overhead will be solved.

Comment: it's a sort of load balancer =)

Comment: What will be faster, create load balancer or create queue logic within service and separate your business logic into worker? And then rip out all services and leave just one. I think, about same time :o)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to run multiple instances of same service, you should adopt asynchronous producer/consumer pattern. Use Task object to kick off a producer, then create many consumers. If your data needs to process in certain order then you will have to arrange consumers to only work on assigned block of data. Otherwise they can pickup their work and start processing.

Following example assumes work can continue in any order. You can fine tune optimize number of consumers based on system resources. Use AppSetting to configure the MaxConsumer and find ideal number that optimizes processing.

Wire-up the start/stop method from your service start/stop, as well as any necessary logging/exception handling. Example here is simplistic and shows the basics of the pattern.

```
public class MyService
{
    BlockingCollection<MyDto> sharedResource = new BlockingCollection<MyDto>();
    CancellationTokenSource cancellation;
    private Task producer;
    private List<Task> consumers;
    //Load/Set this from configuration
    private static readonly int MaxConsumer = 3;

    public void Start()
    {
        this.cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // Start the producer & Consumers, as long running task
        this.producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.Produce(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        this.consumers = new List<Task>();
        for(int i=0; i<MaxConsumer; i++)
        {
            this.consumers.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.Consume() , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
        }

       // If you need primary service loop you can do 
       // something like the following
       // while(!this.cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
       //{
       //        this.cancellation.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
       //}
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.cancellation.Cancel();
        WaitOnTask(producer);
        foreach(var t in this.consumers)
        {
            WaitOnTask(t);
        }
        this.cancellation.Dispose();
    }

    private void WaitOnTask(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                //May want to use timeout
                //instead of blindly waiting
                task.Wait();
            }
        }
        catch(ObjectDisposedException oex)           
        {
            // Task might have been disposed/closed already
        }

    }

    public void Produce()
    {
        var token = this.cancellation.Token;
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Code for your data loading
            if (time to start)
            {
                List<MyDto> rows = LoadData();
                foreach(var data in rows)
                {
                    this.sharedResource.Add(data, token);
                }
            }

            //Wait and repeat
            token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
        }
    }

    public void Consume()
    {
        var token = this.cancellation.Token;
        try
        {
            foreach (var data in this.sharedResource.GetConsumingEnumerable(token))
            {
                // Code for your data processing
                Process(data);
            }
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            // service stop requested, can log here
            // or take action for saving state as needed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My comment is same as to T.S. answer - Good point, thanks for your answer, but i was asking about contribution function. BTW vote up for your solution